# Use javascript to mark current menu item

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I'm working on this site http://fridasofia.se/wand/ and have used JavaScript to mark the current menu item with an arrow.

The problem is that if you use the scrollbar to scroll the page, instead of clicking the menu, the arrow that marks current menu item doesn't follow. How do I make it work?

Thanks /Frida

Answer (score 1):

Such plugins called ScrollSpy. Here is most popular

- [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy)
- [jquery-scrollspy](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at the jQuery Waypoint plugin http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

It should have what you need.